# Subdivision Modifier doesn't make geometry smoother

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

I have this problem with this model.

When I tried to make it more smooth by adding Subdivision Modifier, almost nothing happened. I do not know what to do.
I don't just want it smooth shaded, because I need this file for carving on cnc machine.

The file is here https://uploadnow.io/f/mLKhQKj
Thanks.

<sup>This is original file[image: original file]</sup>

<sup>This is with subd modifier[image: subd modifier]</sup>

Comment: Hello, is this for 3D printing or for an image/scene? If this is for an image or scene, do a right click > Shade Smooth and it will make the shading smoother. Then increase the Subdivision Surface level if necessary

Comment: Hi :). The geometry is basically all triangulated. Once you turn those triangles back into quads, subdivision modifier starts to work just fine :). Need help with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The model is triangulated, that's why Subdivision won't work.
Simply turn those those triangles into quads, Blender will do most of the work:

1. For best results separate the foliage and the column.
2. Select all the foliage faces and go *Face > Tris To quads* with a 180° angle
3. Select the column faces and go *Mesh > CleanUp > Limited Dissolve* with 0.2° max angle. The go *Face > Tris to Quads.*
4. Add a *Subdivision modifier* with enough levels and you're done.

<sup>The foliage. Tris to quads. Done.</sup>
[image]

<sup>The column. Limited Dissolve and then Tris to quads.</sup>
[image]